# Python tkinter change 'open' in the title bar

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to change the part of the title bar that say's 'open' below in the tkinter window-- see the   root.title("Old file selected first") below:

[image]
Here is part of my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Old file selected first") # what i would like to appear instead of 'Open'
root.withdraw()
old_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('.csvfiles', '.csv')])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need the other tk main app running, unless you want to hide the tkinter default box that pops up.

```
import tkFileDialog

old_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('.csvfiles', '.csv')],
                                        title='Old file selected first')
```

See here for more details: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog

Comment: It was actually to hide the default tkinter default box, your solution was exactly what I wanted- thanks very much.